# Java regex to find the 2-word phrases

Tags: java, regex

I have a large text file. I am trying to find all the phrases (any 2 word sequences). Will the regex below do the trick?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\w+\s{1}\w+");
```

I have tried it but it is not working.

Comment: Did you try it? http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: i did not get you. can you please give some example what you want ?

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "not working". Based on what you have given, I think your problem may be that you are not escaping the slashes in your regex.

Comment: This might be problematic depending on what you interpret as one word.  Example: How do you see words separated by `-`?  Like in "Computer-science lessons".  Is that 2 or 3 words to you?  Or something like "Hello beautiful world.  And some more text.".  Try splitting that and see if it does what you expect.  You might want to use '\W' (capital w) instead of '\s'.  '\W' matches all non-word characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work. You need to escape your slashes.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s{1}\\w+");
```

Check the "escape sequences" section [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx should work. Here's a sample implementation in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "ed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error! sit 'voluptatem' " +
                "accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo " +
                "inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. " +
                "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, " +
                "sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt." +
                " Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, " +
                "adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et " +
                "dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis " +
                "nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid " +
                "ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea " +
                "voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem " +
                "eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s\\w+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Gives this (snipped) output:

```
ed ut
unde omnis
iste natus
accusantium doloremque
totam rem
eaque ipsa
quae ab
illo inventore
veritatis et
quasi architecto
beatae vitae
dicta sunt
Nemo enim
ipsam voluptatem
quia voluptas
sit aspernatur
aut odit
aut fugit
...
```